# understanding wildfly hornetq console output

Tags: jboss, wildfly, hornetq

i need help understanding hornetq console output. I am running jms in wildfly 8.1 and in the logs i see this

```
INFO  [stdout] (Thread-1049 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-564338750))
INFO  [stdout] (Thread-1050 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-564338750))
INFO  [stdout] (Thread-1051 (HornetQ-client-global-threads-564338750))
```

is the string 'Thread-1050' means that this is the 1050th thread created

Comment: Probably it is just the default name of the created Thread.

Comment: @AgustinMuñoz so basically means that hornetq has created 1050 threads

Comment: I suppose that those 1051 threads are shared with other Jboss areas (HTTP processing, EJB, DataSourcePools ...) not just the HornetQ ones.